# Spark anonymous function bytecode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, anonymous-class

I'm curious on whether these is a way to see the bytecode of the anonymous class that has been created as `[238]` in a Spark shell environment such as

`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[238]`.

Comment: Why do you need the bytecode? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The reason for that is mostly curiosity. Checking the DAGScheduler on Spark Web UI sometimes gives me a chain of 3 anonymous class just for one simple `.map`. I feel like it's pretty useless to list these anonymous class without giving any more details.

Answer (score 0):

`MapPartitionsRDD[238]` means that this is 239th (numeration starts from 0) RDD created in this context. It does not mean that anonymous class was created.

SparkContext holds information about number of RDDs in this context